# Is there a gcloud API to detect when a Compute Engine server is completely up?

Tags: node.js, kernel, google-compute-engine, startup, gcloud

I create an VM instance. I can connect to it as soon ad the SSH Daemon is started. But this is too early because kernel startup is only at approx. 30%. Is there a `gcloud` or other API to get the VM state when the kernel has finished startup?

```
Nov 18 10:58:51 image-name google: No startup script found in metadata.
Nov 18 10:58:53 image-name kernel: [   27.491829] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:docker[2414]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Nov 18 10:58:53 image-name kernel: [   27.703142] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:docker[2414]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Nov 18 10:58:53 image-name kernel: [   27.735867] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:docker[2414]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Nov 18 10:58:53 image-name kernel: [   27.771732] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:docker[2260]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Nov 18 10:58:53 image-name kernel: [   27.797540] device vethfa3ab85 entered promiscuous mode
Nov 18 10:58:53 image-name kernel: [   27.804420] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethfa3ab85: link is not ready
Nov 18 10:58:53 image-name kernel: [   28.028306] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethfa3ab85: link becomes ready
Nov 18 10:58:53 image-name kernel: [   28.035505] docker0: port 1(vethfa3ab85) entered forwarding state
Nov 18 10:58:53 image-name kernel: [   28.041963] docker0: port 1(vethfa3ab85) entered forwarding state
Nov 18 10:58:53 image-name kernel: [   28.048532] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): docker0: link becomes ready
Nov 18 10:58:54 image-name kernel: [   28.980082] IPv6: eth0: IPv6 duplicate address fe80::42:acff:fe11:1 detected!
->>> about here I can SSH to the server
Nov 18 10:59:08 image-name kernel: [   43.068094] docker0: port 1(vethfa3ab85) entered forwarding state
Nov 18 10:59:53 image-name kernel: [   87.944452] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:docker[2864]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Nov 18 10:59:53 image-name kernel: [   88.001012] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:docker[2864]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Nov 18 10:59:53 image-name kernel: [   88.049510] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:docker[2815]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
->>> I want to know about this point in the startup process
```

My problem is that I can connect to it using SSH when kernel progress is below 30% and some processes are not yet started. I want to detect somehow if the server has completed startup. Or is there a script that can push to the server (through the GCE APIs) to notify me when a server is completely up?

`gcloud compute instances describe image-name` does return the same output from the moment the instance is started till the kernel startup is complete.

(In my case I use the Node.js GCE API, but this should not make any difference.)

Answer (score 1):

Presently I am not aware of any such google native API that can provide a progress of instance start.

*However this is a quick workaround check if this fits your requirement.*

You can either use the [Google Startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) or the native linux rc.local. The concept is the same, so explaining it for the case of rc.local [as it is generic and not tied to google]

We know that the last process in a bootup sequence that runs is rc.local. Any command or script or call that is in this rc.local [which is a sh or bash script by itself] will be executed at the end of boot process.

So the idea would be in the google image in case of rc.local, have a script or a call which send your a notification or writes a output to central system like KV or cloud storage the state that bootup is all done.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Kamran, but here is how I get this done. It depends on using a google startup script and an image where gcloud is installed by default (though you could rework this to just use curl and API calls)

On instance creation/configuration, I set a custom metadata flag: `serverready=False`

At the end of my google startup script, I have this:

`sudo gcloud compute instances add-metadata $(hostname) \
--metadata serverready=True \
--zone $(curl \
"http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/zone" \
-H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"|cut -d/ -f4)`

When I run the instance creation, I can just poll the metadata for the serverready key, and set my app to wait until it sees `serverready=True`